# Decoding a Bouncy Castle ASN.1 object in Scala

Tags: scala, decode, bouncycastle

Hi I'm using Scala with the Bouncy Castle Crypto libraries to read in an X.509 certificate from a file. I'm trying to read the values for some of the extension using the following code:

```
val ext = JcaX509ExtensionUtils.parseExtensionValue(certificate.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.17"))
```

This returns an ASN.1 object as follows.

```
class org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence
```

I now need to decode the ASN.1 object to get the value. However, I seem to be going round in circles as I cannot figure how to easily decode the ASN.1 object without wading though acres of Java code. Surely it can't be that difficult?

This is the code I have and is working so far:

```
import java.io._
 import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory
 import java.security.Security
 import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider._
 import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509ExtensionUtils

 object Main extends App {     
 Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider)
 val provider = new BouncyCastleProvider
 val in = new FileInputStream("cert.cer")
 var certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509", provider)
 val certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(in).asInstanceOf[X509CertificateObject]

 val ext = JcaX509ExtensionUtils.parseExtensionValue(certificate.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.17"))

 println(ext)

}
```

Output:

```
[[2]#4c303037313035392e6d6e73756b2e6164726f6f742e6d61726b73616e647370656e6365722e636f6d]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in extension 2.5.29.17 (subject alternative names) only, why don't you use certificate.[getSubjectAlternativeNames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectAlternativeNames%28%29)()? This gives you a nice object-oriented access to this specific extension... There are, of course, helper functions for other extensions as well.

Comment: Yeah - thanks. Actually I need access to some of the other extensions too. So any pointers will be appreciated. I was hoping that there would be something similar to the certificate.getSubjectAlternativeNames function to get to the other extensions, I haven't been able to find anything other than using the ASN.1 functions directly though.

Comment: So, which extensions are you interested in, that aren't already supported by the X509Certificate class (see Javadoc link in my answer)?